# How to save results of query to file using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database

I want to save the result of the query's execution into txt. 
I do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` INTO OUTFILE '/home/b/myuser/domain.xyz/public_html/first.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

But I have some error like: "Error in query (1045): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

How I can bypass this error? 
I should use these permissions(not write and not edit files), because hackers install various scripts on my site. 
Please, help me.

Comment: How are you connecting to database to execute this query? Error is that you are not able to connect to database. mysql <database> -p<password>

Comment: There should not be any space between -p and your password. Check out this link for more detail: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html

Comment: I do these queries via adminer (one file for using php)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with connection to database. It's not a problem with writing file...

Comment: but I can do "Select * from `users`" without error, but with output in file - error with connection. Why?

Comment: Before doing the query, you must do the connection to the database with the user 'myuser'. Can you copy that piece of code?

Comment: Ok. Has your user "myuser" the right grants to use the schema?

Answer (score 1):

Try following query:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/home/b/myuser/domain.xyz/public_html/first.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM `users`
```